# extract thumbnail from 3d pdf using itextpdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext

When I view a 3D pdf (aka PDF/E) with Adobe Acrobat Reader, it shows a thumbnail on the left side:

[image: 3d pdf viewed with Acrobat Reader]

Is it possible to extract this thumbnail from the pdf using itext or is it generated on the fly by the viewer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, though from what I am seeing I doubt your PDF has a specific thumbnail image and just renders the page in the thumbnail.

First, let's create a PDF that has a thumbnail according to the PDF specification since I couldn't find one. Section 12.3.4 of ISO-3200-2 (the PDF specification) states the following:

> The thumbnail image for a page shall be an image XObject specified by the **Thumb** entry in the page object...

This can be easily created using iText like so:

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(OUTPUT_FILE);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
document.add(new Paragraph("Hello world"));
PdfImageXObject thumbnail = new PdfImageXObject(ImageDataFactory.create(getInput("itext.png")));
pdfDocument.getFirstPage().getPdfObject().put(PdfName.Thumb, thumbnail.getPdfObject());
document.close();
```

Where `getInput("itext.png")` resolves to a full path of our image:

[image]

This gives us [output.pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QPq6YQ0OxY4CQ5RLQlqzrnXrlDW8wafp)

You'll note that neither Acrobat nor Reader display the thumbnail image- they simply render the page. Other readers do use our new thumbnail:

[image]

Since you are using reader I would think this means the thumbnail in your PDF is simply the rendered page since thumbnails appear to be ignored.

To answer your question, getting the thumbnail is simply the reverse of the operation above- we get the Page's dictionary and look for a **/Thumb** entry

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(OUTPUT_FILE);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader);
PdfStream thumbnailStream = pdfDocument.getFirstPage().getPdfObject().getAsStream(PdfName.Thumb);
if (thumbnailStream != null) {
    PdfImageXObject thumbnail = new PdfImageXObject(thumbnailStream);
    BufferedImage image = thumbnail.getBufferedImage();
    //Output to file, memory, etc
}
```

Comment: thank you for your elaborate answer. You are right: the pdf does not contain the thumbnail. I hoped it did, because the view angle was different from the predefined ones in the pdf (+ thumb looks pixelated when you zoom in). It turns out Acrobat DC creates the thumb the first time you open the thumb tab. So if you already manipulated the view, it changes the thumb :)